# pgfopts error when installing ytableau

Tags: packages, installing, pgfkeys, ytableau

I am trying to install ytableau.sty, following the directions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357), and in the ytableau README.  I am running TexShop 2.47 on OS X 10.6. Here's a walkthrough of what I've done, although I suspect I may have gone wrong early on.

First of all, I don't already have it:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

produces

```
! LaTeX Error: File `ytableau.sty' not found.
```

Downloaded `ytableau.ins` from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ytableau/), ran `latex ytableau.ins`, created directory `~/Library/texmf/tex` and copied resulting `ytableau.sty` file to it. Test file now produces

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 173, version
               `2011/06/02' of package pgfopts,
               but only version
               `2008/06/26 v1.0  LaTeX package options with pgfkeys'
               is available.

  ! Undefined control sequence.
  l.174 \ProcessPgfPackageOptions
                                 {/ytableau/options}
```

Repeated process to install the [June 2, 2011 version of pgfopts](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pgfopts).

I still get the same error message. I've tried putting pgfopts in a few different places, namely `~/Library/texmf/tex`, `~/Library/texmf/tex/pgfopts`, `~/Library/texmf/latex` and `~/Library/texmf/latex/pgfopts`, but either LaTeX is still finding the old version or that wasn't the actual problem.

Comment: The packages should be put in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/<packagename>/`.  To test if they are being found, run `kpsewhich <packagefile>` (for example, `kpsewhich pgfopts.sty`).

Comment: Oh, and help with installation is definitely welcome, but it's highly likely that someone will suggest that you upgrade your TeX distribution as that's almost always a good thing to do.  As "almost always" and "always" are not completely synonymous, we recognise that there are circumstances in which that isn't possible.

Comment: Well, that was anti-climactically easy. Thanks! @Herbert If you'd like to increase your reputation by 0.1%, leave an answer and I'll be glad to give you the bounty.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer done ...

Comment: As a very late comment, I suppose I should observe (as the package author) *why* I insisted on this version of `pgfopts`.  In fact, I received a bug report relating to `pgfopts` version 1.x, and it seems that version 2.x is really significantly different.  So you'd have had an error either way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your TeX distribution is out of date, update it ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are running a rather old version of Tex. As you might use an old enough version of MacTeX that there are no updates for it anymore, it would be best to do a clean install of a recent version. I suggest to:

- download the latest version of MacTeX
- install it
- make sure that in the TeX preference panel TeX Live 2012 is selected
- retry to run your file, the version of pgf* in TL2012 should be new enough

Comment: didn't I said this already? ;-)

Comment: No, the point is he might use an old MacTeX where there are no updates any longer. We have to make sure that both the latest is installed *and* activated in the preference pane.