# How to organize properly my LaTeX document files created in TexLive 2012 (on Windows 7)?

Tags: texlive

I've installed `texlive 2012` which has two main folders: `2012` and `texmf-local`. To organize my documents I created a new folder I called `doc` under `texmf-local`. Up to now this has worked fine.

For this purpose is `texmf-local` the correct folder and `doc` a good name or are there better ways?

ADDED. I am the only user. I've forgotten to mention that `texlive 2012` is installed on `Windows 7`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not really a good way to organize your documents. You should think of the folders in in the TeX Live directory as equivalent to folders that belong to a particular application, and you wouldn't normally store your documents created by that application *with* the application.

So you should generally not keep your documents inside the `texlive` folder at all, but wherever makes sense for you within your home folder, just like any other documents you might have.

The only things that go in the `texmf-local` folder are local packages and TeX related stuff that is meant to be accessible to multiple users on a single machine.  If you are the only user, there's little need to use this directory at all, but instead should use your local `texmf` folder.  On a typical Linux system, your local `texmf` folder is located in `~/texmf`; on a Mac, it's `~/Library/texmf`; in Windows it's `\texmf` in your user folder.  See [How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357/2693) for some more information on your local `texmf` folder and how it is used and organized.

So here's a basic organization first Linux/Mac, then Windows paths:

- `/usr/local/texlive/<year>`  Windows: `C:\texlive\<year>`

  - Used only TeXLive; leave this one alone
- `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` Windows `C:\texlive\texmf-local`

  - System wide additions to your TeX distribution
- `/texmf` (Linux); `~/Library/texmf` (Mac); `%USERPROFILE%\texmf` (Windows)

  - User additions to your TeX distribution

Any other document that you create (i.e. any regular user document created with TeX) should simply be placed in any folder that makes sense for your personal organization.  For example, I have a folder for each course I teach, and subfolders for different semesters.  I have folders for research topics and then subfolders for articles I'm writing on those topics.  But these choices are very personal, and you should place your TeX documents in whatever folder structure makes sense for you just like you would any other kind of document you produce.

Answer (score 6):

There are two good reasons for storing files under `texmf-local`:

1. You (and/or any other users on your system) need to have access to packages that are not distributed automatically with TeXLive (or its close sibling, MacTeX). This may be because of licensing restrictions or because the package is non-free (e.g., a font-related package such as `mtpro2`). That way, if and when you update from TeXLive2012 to TeXLive2013, etc., these files will remain accessible to you.
2. You wish to use a "beta" version of a package, where the (established, non-beta) version is distributed with MacTeX but the beta version is not. This is the case, for instance, with the `microtype` package: The official version, distributed with TeXLive, is still 2.4; a beta edition of version 2.5, which may be found on the 'Net, possesses features that you may sorely need and wish to have access to now. By installing the beta version in the `local-texmf` folder, it will be "found" by TeXLive before the official version.

   Note that the `doc` subfolder below `texmf-local` should be used for the user guides and other such files that come with your manually installed packages. That way, you may access the user guides via the `texdoc` command.

All other TeX-related files of yours, such as your TeX documents, should *not* be placed anywhere below `texmf-local`.

Comment: True, but unless you have multiple users/accounts on your machine, there's little advantage to using `texmf-local` vs. your user `texmf` folder, I think.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I guess that if you can be absolutely sure that there will never be any other users on your computer system, then there's definitely no advantage to using `texmf-local` rather than `~/texmf` for these packages. On the other hand, if you think there's at least an outside chance that more than one user will operate on your computer, there's no downside (and quite some upside, AFAICT) to storing these additional packages under `local-texmf` from the get-go.

Comment: At least on a Mac, dealing with things in `/usr/local` requires admin privileges, and the relevant folders are not trivially accessible via the Finder (although since Lion even ~/Library is no longer directly accessible in the Finder) so depending on the user skills, using `texmf-local` is just more of a pain.  I don't know if this is as true for Windows or Linux, however.

Comment: @Mico You need to `texhash` `texmf-local`, whereas your personal tree is always searched and does not need to be hashed. So there are some advantages to using the personal tree, particularly if you want to regularly alter the content.

Comment: @JosephWright -- point well taken. Speaking strictly for myself, I find it quite advantageous at times (mostly because I tend to commit fewer silly mistakes that way!) to have to perform certain activities in `sudo` mode. I find that I run `tlmgr` about twice a week anyway to keep up with new and updated packages; given this setup, having to run `texhash` (via sudo) isn't really much of an extra chore. Naturally, others may well feel rather differently about the burden imposed by these chores.