# override system search path

Tags: linux, texmf

I've installed texlive-2012 on my local user account (under linux), the system has the older version (texlive-2007) in which some packages are missing and I don't have root permission to install those packages.
To force the system recognize my installation I changed some search paths in `~/.bashrc` as suggested in [similar post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-override-default-package):

```
export TEXMF='{/home/avaz/texlive/texmf,/home/avaz/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base,/home/avaz/texlive/texmf-var,/home/avaz/texlive/texmf-config,/home/avaz/texmf,/etc/texmf,confTEXMFSYSVAR,confTEXMFLOCAL,confTEXMFMAIN,confTEXMFDIST}'
export TEXMFHOME='/home/avaz/texlive/texmf'
export TEXMFLOCAL='/home/avaz/texlive/texmf'
```

which obviously `/home/avaz/` is my home folder where texlive-2012 is installed,
but when I run `~/textlive/bin/x86_64-linux/latex myfile.tex` I get the error:

*! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not
found.*

'article.cls' is located in `~/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/`, but I don't why latex doesn't go through this. This is an excerpt I get with `texconfig conf`:

```
=========================== kpathsea variables ===========================
TEXMFMAIN=/usr/share/texmf
TEXMFDIST=/usr/share/texmf
TEXMFLOCAL=/home/avaz/texlive/texmf
TEXMFSYSVAR=/var/lib/texmf
TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/etc/texmf
TEXMFHOME=/home/avaz/texlive/texmf
```

Have I done something wrong or anything left which I have to change to work it out?

Comment: If you remove the changes you made to `~/.bashrc` and ask the terminal `echo $TEXMF`, what do you get? In any case, you need to change `PATH` so that the binaries of TeX Live 2012 are found before the system wide ones.

Comment: The same thing as above in { } but another error comes in _'tcfmgr.map' not found_. could you tell what exactly I have to change in `PATH`?

Comment: Try `export PATH=~/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}` in your `.bashrc` file and restart the terminal. *Don't* set `TEXMF` and similar variables.

Comment: Thanks alot! the 'article.cls' error resolved. Now I have another error for packages like graphicx (.sty files). I think I've changed something that I have to include those paths in my `.bashrc` otherwise I get 'tcfmgr.map' error

Comment: The binaries of TeX Live configure themselves to use the correct paths and set internally the necessary environment variables like `TEXMF` based on `texmf.cnf`. You generally have to set nothing in the environment, except the path to the binaries.

Comment: I just found it out. previously I used `declare -x TEXMF=...` I suppose it sets `TEXMF` as a constant variable I removed it with `unset`. Now it works as you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binaries of TeX Live configure themselves to use the correct paths for file searches and internally set variables such as `TEXMF` and friends based on the values established in the `texmf.cnf` file they are able to find because it's in a fixed position with respect to the directory containing the binaries.

This said, you have only to modify the `PATH` variable; based on your message, it seems that stating

```bsh
export PATH=~/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}
```

in your `~/.bashrc` file should be sufficient to solve the problems.

Make sure that no variable whose name starts with `TEX` is set in the environment (well, no variable among those that are found in `texmf.cnf`; in case of doubt consult an expert).