# How to specify the path for a package?

Tags: packages, paths

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-override-default-package)

In the (linux) server in which the basic LaTeX suite (TexLive 2009) was installed, I can run LaTeX with some basic packages. I can upload the package to my local home directory but I cannot have it installed to the system. So is there any way to specify the path of the package in my home folder so the latex interpreter will find that?

I tried to upload the .sty files to my home folder but I cannot run texhash without root right. I google that issue, someone suggests to upload the .sty to $HOME/.texlive, I tried but seems it doesn't work. I have very little experience on linux and I use something other than texlive on windows, I need more direction.

Comment: Packages in your local `texmf` folder are always found first, and will override any on the main system.  In a linux system your local `texmf` is simply `~/texmf` but it needs to have a particular folder structure. See [How to have local package override default package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357/2693).

Comment: Good. We'll close this question as a duplicate then.