# How do I query pdflatex for its package search path as well as modify it?

Tags: packages, installing, texinputs

I am trying to install a local package draftwatermark to override an out-of-date version of the package, by applying the answer in [How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-override-default-package) .

I have placed the files draftwatermark.ins and draftwatermark.dtx from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/draftwatermark into the directory

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/draftwatermark
```

Unfortunately, based on version number, pdflatex is still using the global version.
Therefore, I am wondering how I can interrogate pdflatex for its package search path, and modify it without root privileges.

Comment: You may have discovered that there's a small bug in the version of `draftwatermark` on CTAN; while the package has version 1.1, it still advertises itself as version 1.0; try `kpsewhich draftwatermark.sty` from the command line to see what path is used for loading it. However, you should first unpack `draftwatermark.sty` by running pdflatex on `draftwatermark.ins`

Comment: Also, the link above does not have draftwatermark.sty.
Where can I get an authoritative version of this file?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that I did not realize I needed to run latex on the ins file to generate the sty. Previously I had been working with packages that already had the sty file.

When I ran latex on the .ins file and placed the sty file in the above directory, it worked correctly even though the bug with reporting is still there.