# Faroese language package

Tags: texlive, languages, babel, contribute

I am working on a project in faroese, where I need to use the localization features offered by babel. I cannot find a faroese babel package, and when searching for it, there seems to be some confusion, where faroese and icelandic are [mixed together](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Icelandic_and_Faroese).

I want to create a faroese babel package, but I need some guidance doing this. First of all, I do not event know where to find an example on how to implement at language package.

I tried searching my computer (MacTeX distro), and I found babel files in `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/source/generic/babel-danish/danish`, and tried to create similar babel-faroese directories and files, but it did not seem the work. (Likely I need to update some references or something).

Is there a guide on how to create babel language packs? I think I can rewrite the `.ins` and `.dtx` files in that folder to match the faroese language, but I have absolutely no idea on how it should be packaged and committed to the repositories, or even how to get my own TeX distribution to use the files...

Comment: Having sopport for feroese is certainly welcome. Please, read the following file on contributed languages: http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/required/babel/base/CONTRIB

Comment: I have created a GitHub repository for the language file: https://github.com/ragnar123/faroese-babel-package. I will upload to CTAN when the package is ready - so far I have only implemented what I needed at this time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should never create new files within the actual directories of your distribution. Instead you should use the proper local `texmf` directories.

You can create a `faroese.ldf` file modeled on the `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-danish/danish.ldf` file, and install it in your local `texmf` folder. On a Mac, this is `~/Library/texmf`, and it's sensible to make a `tex/generic/babel` folder for the file.  See the following for how to set up such a local folder.

- [How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357/2693)

This way you don't need to update any of the system databases etc.

The main `babel` package is actively maintained by Javier Bezos but new language definitions are now maintained independently. See the following link for information on putting a new language definition file on CTAN:

- http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/required/babel/base/CONTRIB

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not aware of a local `texmf` folder, but editing files belonging to root:wheel felt wrong and almost like a criminal act to be editing these files. :-) 
I have copied the danish.ldf file to my local directory, renamed it to faroese, and it works. Now I will spend some time to adjust it to faroese, and send it to the maintainer, when it is ready.