# Where to put tikzlibraryarrows.new.code.tex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've downloaded the tikzlibraryarrows.new.code.tex library from source forge and can use it in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% for resizing arrow head
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.new}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% collimated light
\foreach \y in {2, 0, -2}
  \draw[-stealth new, arrow head=2mm] (-10,\y) -- (-3,\y);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Only when I place the tikzlibraryarrows.new.code.tex file in the same directory as the rest of my source. I've read that you put these files in your "personal tree" and then use texhash. Where is this?

I've tried:

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/arrowsnew/tikzlibraryarrows.new.code.tex
```

and

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/arrowsnew/tikzlibraryarrows.new.code.tex
```

followed by texhash but they still don't seem to be found, and I'm greeted with the following message:

```
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                                  \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.8 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.new}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to have local package override default package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357)

Comment: right on. That was what I was looking for.

Comment: You might as well install the [recent CVS version of TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2044/16595) and use the new `arrows.meta` library that improves the arrows much more.