# Can't use biblatex-chicago with clean TeX Live 2014 install; textcitedelim undefined

Tags: biblatex

After a clean install of Cygwin 64-bit with TeX Live 2014 (all packages), I can no longer use biblatex-chicago cleanly.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
a~\autocite{kastenholz}.
\end{document}
```

This works with a clean 2013 install. Did something change, or am I doing this wrong?

First error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \textcitedelim undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.795 \renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}
                                    {%
```

Second error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \iffinalcitedelim undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.2765 \renewcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}
                                        {%
```

Comment: This compiles fine for me (TL 2014 on a Mac). Check the log file to make sure you're not using a local version of `biblatex-chicago`.

Comment: (ugh - line breaks; using the default installed by distro; can you see what version you have installed of the following file?)
$ head -1 /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.cbx

% $Id: chicago-notes.cbx,v 0.9.7.95 2014/01/29 11:26:57 dfussner Exp $

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.bbx)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.cbx

! LaTeX Error:...

Comment: From `\listfiles`: biblatex-chicago 2013/10/29 v 2.8
 
biblatex 2014/06/25 v2.9a chicago-notes.cbx 2014/01/29 v 2.8a
 
biblatex2 2014/06/25 v2.9a

Comment: Perhaps that's the issue; I'm using biblatex-chicago.sty 2013/10/29 v 2.8; biblatex.sty 2013/01/10 v2.5; biblatex2.sty 2013/01/10 v2.5; chicago-notes.cbx 2014/01/29 v 2.8a

Now to figure out how to update biblatex in Cygwin...

Comment: Doesn't `tlmgr` work?

Comment: I don't have admin rights on this machine; install was from Cygwin by administrator. I'm not going to be able to test if this is the solution until Monday, though I think that may be it. And that assumes the one with admin rights is here Monday...

Comment: You should have a local `texmf` folder that doesn't need admin rights, so you could put it there.  It needs to have the correct internal directory structure: see [How to have local package override default package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357) for an example of the structure.

Comment: You need matching `biber` for `biblatex` if you use it. (Which is probably so with `biblatex-chicago`.)

Comment: Yep - mismatching biblatex and biblatex-chicago versions were the culprit. I'll verify that I'm using the latest version in the Cygwin repositories and file a bug with them about the incompatibility.

Alan or cfr - do you want to create an answer so I can accept it and give you the credit you both deserve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by currently mismatched biblatex and biblatex-chicago versions in the latest Cygwin 64-bit packages.

biblatex 2.8
biblatex-chicago 2.9a

Thanks to Alan Munn in the comments of the original question for helping me track this down.