# Mac 10.9.4 & MacTeX (Installation of .sty file)

Tags: errors, installing

I hope you can help.

I was a fairly regular user of LaTeX, only for Open University assignments (even attended a TUG course in London!!) but have had about 18 months off and returned with a new platform! Mac!

As a previous Windows user, I had set up everything OK (with a little help) - but am now embarking on this through the world of Apple.

Previously I was used to TeXworks as the editor and had downloaded a tma.sty file from an OU forum which assisted in the layout tremendously... I had adjusted and added things and eventually re-wrote some of the .sty file to reduce the preamble in my OU assignments.

However, porting to Mac has left me somewhat stumped!  I have downloaded MacTeX and performed the 'whole' installation.  I have booted up TexShop and opened a previously created .tex file.

On opening a previous .tex document it opens fine, the PDF partner opens fine, but the minute I press 'Typeset' I get a ! LaTeX Error: File 'OUTMA.sty' not found.

I know I need to save my .sty file somewhere... but where?
I have a TeX foler under Applications that has;
Excalibur-4.0.7 [folder]
FixMacTeX2013.pkg
LaTeXIT
LuaTeX-and-XeTeX [folder]
TeX Live Utility 
TeXShop
FixMacTeX2014.pkg
BibDesk
and 3 x .pdf files

And I remember something about refreshing a file name database once this was done (but again, how)?!

I'm sure I will be fine once I have it started... HELP!

If it helps, I am running TeXShop v. 3.41 and have updated everything I can using TeX Live

Thanks in advance - Simon

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files: you are looking for `<home>/Library/texmf`, where you'll need to make a `tex/latex/local` folder and put the file in there. No need to hash.

Comment: BTW, we must have met if you came to the UK-TUG training in London :-)

Comment: Thanks Joseph,On the Mac, I have a [home]/library/TeX/Local/ path that has the following folders; bibtex, dvips, fonts, metapost, tex and web2c.

Comment: That's different: you may need to make `<home>/Library/texmf` as a first step.

Comment: Do I therefore create the following; [home]/library/texmf-local/tex[NEW]/latex[NEW]/local[NEW]/OUTMA.sty?

Comment: Sorry - the folder said local (but it was a shortcut), when I clicked on it its 'revealed' name was texmf-local

Comment: There's a pretty complete answer to this at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-override-default-package/8359#8359 (with a script that will create the basic TDS hierarchy).

Comment: Thanks both... all done - had to create a file structure as you said Joseph, the native file structure as created when installed was slightly different.