# slashbox.sty not found after download from CTAN

Tags: errors, packages, mactex

I am using Mac OSX and when compiling using TeXShop I get the error `! LaTeX Error: File 'slashbox.sty' not found.`  I have downloaded `slashbox.zip` from CTAN and placed it in my `~/Applications/Tex` folder where all my Tex files including TexShop are located but still receive the same error.  How do I get `slashbox.sty` to be recognized / found?

Comment: `MacTeX` includes `TeX Live Utility` which the MacOSX version of TeX Live Package Manager. You should use it to install any package that's part of the distribution. I suppose you didn't install slashbox in a directory searched by TeX.

Comment: @Bernard I took a look at the TeX Live Utility, but it doesn't have slashbox as a package option.  Another answer suggests this is because what is part of Tex Live is a subset of what is found on CTAN.  To the second point, do you know where TeX would normally search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's right, I didn't know (personally, I use MiKTeX). But it's an old package (1993!) and the TeX Catalogue On Line says it is superseded by `diagbox` which has backwards compatibility and is included in TeX Live.

If you absolutely want to install it, the files must be installed in `texmf-local`. More precisely, `slashbox.sty` and `slashbox.tex` shall be installed in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/latex/slashbox/` and the  documentation `slashbox.pdf` in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc/latex/slashbox/`, in order to respect the TDS (TeX Directory Structure).

Comment: On the Mac, local additions are typically stored in `~/Library/texmf` See [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252) and [How to have local package override default package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357).

Comment: As far as I know, every TeX Live installation has a texmf-local that is installed parallel to main texlive (/usr/local/texlive/2014) for the latest version. I also know the unix structure is hidden to basic users. I would try to find `/texlive/texmf-local` and would iinstall the files therein as indicated. Then run `mktexlsr` from the command line.

Comment: There is very little to be gained by installing things there if you are a single user. And installation in the local `texmf` doesn't require running `mktexlsr`, nor does it require admin privileges, and so most users (including experienced ones like myself) use the local `texmf`.

Comment: You're certainly right. As I said, I'm not very experienced about TeX Line on Mac. I suppose it's mainly useful if there are several users and you want them to have immediate access to the files – at least that's the way I understand it.

Comment: In my case, files had to be stored in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/slashbox` and `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/slashbox/` and I had to run `mktexlsr`