# R to LaTeX with knitr and pandoc (error in a guide)

Tags: packages, r, knitr

I want to follow the guide http://kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2014/01/23/plain-text/ since my document http://rpubs.com/lindberg/110268 need to be pushed to latex for a better read.

The tex says "The heavy lifting is done by the org-preamble-pdflatex.sty and memoir-article-styles files. If you install these files where LaTeX can find them—i.e., if you can compile a LaTeX document based on this example—then you are good to go." So I installed these three .sty packages and put them in my folder
`/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir-article-styles/`

At first I put them in 
`/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/base/`
but that did not work out. And I read on
the stackexchange question
[How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-override-default-package/8359#8359)
that is should be in the folder
`tex/latex/name-of-package/`

Now I download your example.tex and compile it, but run into a lot of errors.

The errors can be seen here:

[image]

The log files is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ih7mj7398gwottn/article.log?dl=1

I do not know how to proceed, what I need is to render the example.tex correctly so that I can proceed with the rest of the guide.

Comment: Check the contents of your memoir-article-styles.sty: it looks like you have an HTML or XML file there instead of a LaTeX file. I can guarantee that line 6 of Kieran's file has no `#` symbols. I'd also just drop all the .sty files in the same directory as your generated .tex file -- once you have it working for one article, you can move the .sty files into the TeX folder structure.

Comment: @MikeRenfro here is the content of the .sty file https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqyatt609eui5xp/jl_150924_092426memoir-article-styles-sty-content.txt?dl=1

Comment: @MikeRenfro here is the content of the article.tex https://www.dropbox.com/s/3d2t1208dnu6rp7/article.tex?dl=1

Comment: Right, and if you look at that style file's contents you just posted, it's an HTML file (looks like a you saved a page off of Github). Get his actual .sty file from Github in its original format. It appears you can get them from the bottom of [his LaTeX Templates and Styles page](http://kjhealy.github.io/latex-custom-kjh/).

Comment: I downloaded the zip "kjhealy-latex-custom-kjh-a0dbd45" and followed your advice "drop all the .sty files in the same directory as your generated .tex file" so I duplicate the file article.tex and name it article3.tex then I put it in the folder "jltestar" together with all the .sty packages, but I get errors and no output. This is my folder: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/25qcy6l7xin1zli/AADLhvwEm3KyNusfmv7Fbdcma?dl=0

Comment: Are the only errors you get messages like "must use XeLaTeX and not pdflatex"?

Comment: @MikeRenfro !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty:43: Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
                                                  
l.43  }
       
? 
 ) )

Comment: So build it with XeLaTeX or lualatex, then. That error will go away, at least.