# Finding and configuring my texmf tree

Tags: texmf

I'm trying to install a new style file that doesn't come by default with LaTeX.  I'm on a Linux Mint computer, and installed LaTeX with a simple

```
sudo apt install texlive
```

or something like that, if I recall correctly.  Now as I search for my texmf directory, I've found two (which I found by following some instructions at various pages on the internet).  One is at `/var/lib/texmf` and the other is at `/usr/local/share/texmf/`.  The former has the folders:

```
dvipdfmx/
dvips/
fonts/
luatex-cache/
tex/
web2c/
xdvi/
...
```

as well as seven files, one of them for instance is `fmtutil.cnf-DEBIAN`.

With some blind exploration, I don't find any `.sty` files in any of the sub-folders.  In the other directory, `/usr/local/share/texmf/` the directory is entirely empty.

So unless I just haven't explored the sub-folders of the first directory enough, I don't think either of these are where LaTeX is looking for its `.sty` files.  So how do I find the correct directory?  When I type `which tex` it gives me `usr/bin/tex` but in that directory, I don't see any other file that seems related to LaTeX.

When I run `texhash` it returns

```
texhash: /usr/local/share/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.
```

Since I don't really know what I'm doing I didn't want to run `texhash` as root, but this sort of makes me think that the texmf tree has to be in one of these directories ... so I'm just confused at this point.

[Edit:  I've seen some people suggest that there might be a texmf tree at the home directory, but there isn't one for me.  That is to say there is no `texmf` directory located in my `~/` directory.]

[Further edit:  Also when I type `echo $TEXMFHOME` it returns a blank line.]

[Further edit: Per egreg's comment I entered `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` which returns `/home/myname/texmf` but this directory doesn't exist.]

Comment: `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` is the right command line.

Comment: @egreg So when I do that, it returns `/home/myname/texmf`.  However, no such directory exists.

Comment: If the directory doesn't exist, then make it yourself. It needs to have the structure shown in the answer to this question [How to have local package override default package](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357).

Comment: @AlanMunn So you do this all manually by making a bunch of `mkdir` commands?  And just by making the directories, tex will automatically find them?  Do I need to find whatever "executable" file tex is using and move it too?  And it won't "forget" the old location of the default `.sty` files, like `amsmath` which I've been using up until now without issue?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to make all of the structure, just the stuff you need. So minimally you will probably need `texmf/tex/latex` for latex packages and if you want documentation for a package to be found by `texdoc` it should be in `texmf/doc`.

Comment: you have installed the "system" tex via sudo so that and the default tex tree are not writable under a normal account but the default search path includes TEXMFHOME set to a texmf tree in your home directory (which does not need to exist) so if you make it and put just your updated files in there, then  all standard files will be found in the existing system location, but it will look in `~/texmf` first and find any updated files there

Comment: @AlanMunn Cool, did it, everything works wonderfully!  Thanks, and if you want to turn this into an answer I'll accept it.  Out of just passing curiosity, though, do you happen to know where my other default `.sty` files are located?  If you don't know off the top of your head, no worries, it really is just gnawing curiosity for me at this point.

Comment: You can find the location of any particular file by using `kpsewhich`. E.g. `kpsewhich article.cls` will tell you the exact path TeX uses to find the `article.cls` that is loaded when you say `\documentclass{article}`.  But basically most of your stuff is in the `/usr/local/share/texmf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local additions should not be put into the system `texmf` directory, i.e., `/usr/local/share/texmf`, but instead should be put into your home `texmf` folder. This folder is not created automatically, so you need to create it yourself.

The location of your local `texmf` can be found by using the command:

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
```

On a Linux system, this will typically be `~/texmf` (`/home/<username>/texmf`).  You can create the folder yourself but it must conform to the TeX Directory Structure. See:

- [How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357)

Once you've done this you don't need to do anything else for packages to be found; TeX looks in this directory first.

Answer (score 0):

`texconfig conf` can give all kpathsea variables too:

```
=========================== kpathsea variables ===========================
TEXMFMAIN=/usr/texmf-dist
TEXMFDIST=/usr/texmf-dist
TEXMFLOCAL=//texmf-local
TEXMFSYSVAR=/usr/texmf-var
TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/usr/texmf-config
TEXMFVAR=/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-var
TEXMFCONFIG=/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-config
TEXMFHOME=/home/firestar/texmf
VARTEXFONTS=/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-var/fonts
TEXMF={{}/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/firestar/texmf,!!//texmf-local,!!/usr/texmf-config,!!/usr/texmf-var,!!/usr/texmf-dist}
SYSTEXMF=/usr/texmf-var://texmf-local:/usr/texmf-dist
TEXMFDBS={!!//texmf-local,!!/usr/texmf-config,!!/usr/texmf-var,!!/usr/texmf-dist}
WEB2C={{}/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/firestar/texmf,!!//texmf-local,!!/usr/texmf-config,!!/usr/texmf-var,!!/usr/texmf-dist}/web2c
TEXPSHEADERS=.:{{}/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/firestar/texmf,!!//texmf-local,!!/usr/texmf-config,!!/usr/texmf-var,!!/usr/texmf-dist}/{dvips,fonts/{enc,type1,type42,type3}}//
TEXCONFIG={{}/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/firestar/texmf,!!//texmf-local,!!/usr/texmf-config,!!/usr/texmf-var,!!/usr/texmf-dist}/dvips//
ENCFONTS=.:{{}/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/firestar/texmf,!!//texmf-local,!!/usr/texmf-config,!!/usr/texmf-var,!!/usr/texmf-dist}/fonts/enc//
TEXFONTMAPS=.:{{}/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/firestar/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/firestar/texmf,!!//texmf-local,!!/usr/texmf-config,!!/usr/texmf-var,!!/usr/texmf-dist}/fonts/map/{kpsewhich,pdftex,dvips,}//
```

That is better than one `kpathsea` command at a time.