# texmf install script doesn't work

Tags: packages, installing, mactex, texmf

I wanted to use the script mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-override-default-package/8359#8359) to install a local `texmf` structure on a Mac. When I click on the script, I get the message "Local texmf folder already exists," but when I click on "Take me there," I get a message saying that the directory wasn't found. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of mac osx do you have?

Comment: And do you use mactex or normal texlive?

Comment: @samcarter Sierra 10.12.6. And I use MacTex.

Comment: @crmdgn Can you open a terminal and check what `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` says?

Comment: @samcarter ~/Library/texmf