# How to "automate" editing a custom package?

Tags: package-writing, directory

I wrote a custom package with my most used commands and it works great. However I find the process of keeping it up to date a little involved. Because the `/usr/local/texlive/...` directory is owned by root, I can't write changes from the editor directly to it. On the other hand I don't have a `~/.tex` or any (la)tex-related directory in my home folder. So what I'm doing now is to edit a copy of the `.sty` file that resides in my `~/` folder and always save it when I make a change. Then I `sudo cp` it to `/usr/local/texlive/...`, I rebuild the index and finally I can use it.

Is there a quicker way to make the changes readily available to my system so that I can try them right after having made them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never need to store files in `/usr/local/texlive/...` really. Instead just create a local `texmf` folder. Changes you make there will be instantly available to any file and without the need to run `texhash` (`mktexlsr`).  See the following question on how to do this:

- [How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357/2693)

Comment: Cool, I read about the `texmf` folder, but I didn't know I could/had to create one myself if it didn't exist. I now read your other answer and it works. It even goes to the extent that TexStudio (nice program) suggests me the new commands I created when I start typing them. And all without rehashing anything. Sorry, but I had to get this out: I'm very impressed and a happy LaTeX user!