# Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files to get them working with TinyTeX?

Tags: packages, installing, distributions, tinytex

I used to have my local `.sty` and `.cls` files in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/some_folder/` which worked for the default `pdflatex` of TeX Live just fine. After an installation of TinyTeX, these files are still there, but `pdflatex`, relying now on TinyTeX, can't find these files anymore.

So far so good, but I have no idea where to but the local files within the TinyTeX architecture.

- I tried to put these in the folder `~/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/some_folder/` but without any success.
- Or must I update my search path?

Any help appreciated ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2021-03-03**

As of 2021-03-03, new installations of TinyTeX should have a `texmf-home` folder for user level local additions. This folder must conform the the structure outlined here: [How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357/2693) but should not require any other action for packages to be found.

**Older versions of TinyTeX**

If your TinyTeX folder doesn't contain a `texmf-home` folder, but only contains a `texmf-local` folder, then the following applies:

The TinyTeX distribution sets `$TEXMFHOME` to be the same as `$TEXMFLOCAL` so you should put your local additions into

```
~/.TinyTeX/texmf-local/tex/latex/
```

When you have done this, you will need to update the ls-R file for that directory by doing:

```
mktexlsr ~/.TinyTeX/texmf-local
```

Then your local files should be found.

Comment: Thanks, that worked just fine! Just for my understanding, should the local files be placed within `~/.TinyTeX/texmf-local/tex/latex/` or within `~/.TinyTeX/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/`?

Comment: @moremo No, the folder has to conform to the structure in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357/2693) but otherwise no. So you don't need to put things inside the `local` folder; you can put them inside their own named folders, or without any further internal structure. The main thing to be aware of is that `.bst` and `.bib` files need to be inside the `bibtex/bib` and `bibtex/bst` folders, not the `tex` folder.